# Lower, Lower, Higher Pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, pattern-matching

I have to make a pattern which goes highest, lower, lower, higher, in Javascript.

Only the first number is the highest, for example:

Highest, lower, lower, higher, lower, lower, higher, lower, lower, higher...

Input: [12,34,56,64,43,123,56,87,13,67]

Returns: [123,87,56,67,56,43,64,34,12,13]

The array can be as long or short as possible. It has to be able to account for duplicates and fix them in the pattern (duplicates cant be beside eachother).

This is what I tried:

1. sort the array
2. get the highest number and append that to the new array
3. get the two smallest numbers of the array and append
4. get the largest available number of the array and append
5. get the next two smallest numbers and append
6. get the next largest number and appendf

i repeated this process and it worked. the issue is it can't account for duplicates.

123 13 12 87 43 34 67 56 56 64

is what i got but the two 56s were adjacent.

Comment: why not strip out duplicates after the stuff that otherwise works ok?

Comment: Before selecting a number, check if it's the same as the previous one. If so, skip it and try the next one that satisfies the criteria. Do this in a loop until you find one you can use.

Comment: @dandavis I think duplicates are supposed to be in the result, just not adjacent to each other.

Comment: What should happen if the last two numbers are duplicates?

Comment: @dandavis the duplicates must be in there

Comment: @dandavis ill try out your method